# How to execute Django view through Stripe signal?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, stripe-payments

After a customer has unlocked a post, I want to add his profile to the list of profiles that have unlocked the post.

```
def unlockpostview(request, post_id):
    if userthatisunlockingprofile in post.unlockedby.all():
        pass
    else:
        post.unlockedby.add(userthatisunlockingprofile)
```

When the user has paid I listen to the Stripe's `succeeded` event and execute the view like so:

```
if (result.paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
          $.get("{% url 'postsapp:unlockpostview' post.post_id %}")
          window.alert("Unlocked")
        }
```

My problem was that anybody could go to the post and simply add `/unlock` to the end of the URL and execute the view.
Then I added

```
if request.is_ajax():
```

to the view but this still isn't the optimal solution.
I do not expect a complete solution to this but please point me in the right direction if you can. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**in POST request you don't give variables to the URL and also a CSRF token is a gift with it. And dump users can't send POST requests on browser easily**

```
if (result.paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{% url 'postsapp:unlockpostview' %}",
            headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
            },
            data: {
                'operation': 'unlock_action',
                'post_id': '{{ post.post_id }}', //quotes are important:)
                'user': {{ request.user.id }}
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                if(response.success == true){
                 window.alert("Unlocked")
                }
             },
             error: function(rs, e) {
              console.log('error')
             }
          });
        }
```

**Just remove the post_id attribute from your url or:**

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('unlockpostview/', views.unlockpostview, name="unlockpostview"),
]
```

views.py:

```
def unlockpostview(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.get("operation") == "unlock_action":
            post = Post.objects.get(id=request.POST.get("post_id"))
            userthatisunlockingprofile = User.objects.get(id=request.POST.get("user"))
            #then your logic
            if userthatisunlockingprofile in post.unlockedby.all():
                ctx={"succes":True,"status":"exist"}
            else:
                post.unlockedby.add(userthatisunlockingprofile)
                ctx={"succes":True,"status":"created"}
            return JsonResponse(ctx)
    else:
        return redirect("home")
    #Here is the security
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I had to basically call ajax inside ajax. The only problem left is that the Stripe element doesn't get rendered when i pass "'post_id': {{post.post_id}}," but it works when I hardcode it i
n like this "'post_id': "2a921012-e73e-42f6-a334-11eb556b6d28"," but I'll figure it out

Thanks so much again

Comment: For future reference, I had to use 'post_id': "{{ post.post_id }}", not 'post_id': {{ post.post_id }},

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, you are right quotes are important. Happy Hacking!